# Как исправить или изменить GET запрос правильно? Для API

Tags: php, .htaccess

Помогите исправить GET запрос. Все вроде бы работает нормально, но мне нужно получать информацию не просто по ссылке в https://tmdb.com/ или вот так https://tmdb.com/index.php?id=45782
нужно вместо ?id=45782 сделать https://tmdb.com/45782
Как это организовать или исправить? Правка разными методами .htaccess не помогло.

```
session_start();
// TMDB API ' . urldecode(http_build_query($params))
// $id = $_GET['id'];
$id = $_GET['id'] = '45782';
$tmdbparam = array(
'api_key' => "KEY", // Или используйте временный ключ - 167bec11ad1d2c8ced5935a645b04e1c
'language' => "ru-RU"
); 
$tmdb = file_get_contents('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/'.$id.'?' . urldecode(http_build_query($tmdbparam)));
$tmdb = json_decode($tmdb, true);
//TMDB API

/*else
{
    die('Такой фильм не найден.');
}
header("Location: /info");
}
*/

echo '<pre>'; print_r($tmdb); echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Для чего у вопроса метки `[javascript]` и `[.htaccess]`? Ответы с решениями на JS или на редиректах (для собственных API-серверов) тоже подойдут?

Comment: Да. Я что буду отсылать все то что я использую. Мне нужно только решение по изменении ЧПУ хоть на js хоть ajax.

Comment: каша какая-то написана. Разъясните нормально логику вашего приложения. что оно делает вообще. Получает какой-то запрос, и в ответ делает апи запрос или что это вообще такое?
Если суть в том, что вас на своем сервере надо заменить ссылки index.php?id=.. на просто /123123/ то об этом и спрашивайте, знания про какие-то апи тут излишни для сути вопроса.

Comment: @teran, да на просто site.ru/123/ вместо site.ru?id=123

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(\d+)/?$  index.php?id=$1 [L]`

Comment: @teran, опередил меня))

Comment: `url_decode` еще из кода своего уберите он там не к месту

Answer (score 0):

JS (для серверного ответа в JSON, например), без обработки ошибок:

```
// origin == 'scheme://hostname'
const response => await fetch(`${origin}/${id}/`).then(r => r.json());
```

---

.htaccess (`/1234/`  `/index.php?id=1234`):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?(\d+)/?$
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?id=%1 [L]
```

---

В серверном скрипте на PHP - получение query параметра `id` все так же через `$_GET`, т.е. концептуально ничего не меняется (только запихивать значение в `$_GET['id']` не надо, ведь оно ожидается в запросе от клиента).

Comment: так работает site.ru?id=45782 так нет site.ru/45782 Дичь какая-то. Объект не найден

Comment: @АлинаХром, значит, нужно с сервером разбираться, смотреть логи запросов, и т.д..

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт!. всего 2 строчки в начале:

```
<?php
$url1 = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on')) ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$url1 = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$tmdbparam = array(
'api_key' => "167bec11ad1d2c8ced5935a645b04e1c", // Или используйте временный ключ - 167bec11ad1d2c8ced5935a645b04e1c
'language' => "ru-RU"
); 
$tmdb = file_get_contents('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/tv/'.$url1.'?' . urldecode(http_build_query($tmdbparam)));
$tmdb = json_decode($tmdb, true);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($tmdb); echo '</pre>';
?>
```